# Как в Python подключить к скрипту настройки из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, config

Пишу бот для инсты на InstaPy. Поскольку в InstaPy очень много настроек, хочу вывести их в отдельный текстовый файл чтобы при смене настроек не переписывать их в исходнике, а просто поправить в файле. Подскажите как это сделать чтобы не пришлось в коде нагараживать кучу if? Просто пока толком не понимаю как правильно это сделать.

Comment: Где там вообще может пригодиться куча if'ов? Берёте настройку из файла и используете её. Всё.

Comment: попробуйте вот эту штуку https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй Python файл

```py
import filename
```